# How to have mobile only elements

Tags: html, css, mobile, display

I'm using this to try have elements show only in mobile:

```css
.ms {display: inline;}
```

it's set to this in the computer version:

```css
.ms {display: none;}
```

It works fine when I test it in the offline file I test everything with, but when I upload it to my host it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the stylesheet is loading? That the css and html files are in the same relative directories to one another? "/css/style.css" means something else on a local computer than on a server. Also, are the filenames the same, including casing? For a file named "style.css", a reference like `href="Style.css"` may work on one computer, but not another. And you're not using a "file://" protocol by mistake somewhere?

Comment: Is your host or browser caching non html files? Try opening it in incognito mode, and press Shift+F5 to refresh the page. Also try clearing ur site cache.